# Преобразование базы в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Добрый день. Не могли бы посоветовать как решить такую задачу:
Есть база данных с датой и предикатами. Необходимо транспонировать базу следующим образом:

Было:

```
date. x.  y
1.    a.  1
2.    a.  2
3.    a.  2
1.    b.  0
2.    b.  4
3.    b.  1
```

Стало:

```
X. date1. date2 date3
a.  1.      2.    3
b.  0.      4.    1
```

Заранее благодарю за советы.

Comment: полетело форматирование...
Было : столбцы (дата, группирующая переменная, значение показателя)
Необходимо: 
индекс - группирующая переменная
Название столбцов - все даты
значения - значение показателя

Answer (score 1):

**Способ 1:**

```
In [63]: df.set_index(['x', 'date'])['y'].unstack('date').add_prefix('date')
Out[63]:
date  date1  date2  date3
x
a         1      2      2
b         0      4      1
```

**Способ 2:**

```
In [64]: df.pivot(index='x', columns='date', values='y').add_prefix('date')
Out[64]:
date  date1  date2  date3
x
a         1      2      2
b         0      4      1
```

**Способ 3:**

```
In [9]: df.pivot_table(index='x', columns='date', values='y', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
Out[9]:
date  1  2  3
x
a     1  2  2
b     0  4  1
```

**Способ 4:**

```
In [10]: pd.crosstab(df['x'], df['date'], df['y'], aggfunc='sum')
Out[10]:
date  1  2  3
x
a     1  2  2
b     0  4  1
```

**Способ 5:**

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['x','date'])['y'].sum().unstack('date')
Out[11]:
date  1  2  3
x
a     1  2  2
b     0  4  1
```

Comment: Спасибо, с df.pivot способ нашла, а с set_index - не знала)

Comment: @DundukArt, всегда пожалуйста! Добавил еще несколько способов...

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame.pivot( index = None , columns = None , values ​​= None )